# Python - facebook scrape returning a empty json file

Tags: python-3.x, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping

I'm trying for the first time scraping facebook data with Python, following trough some videos lessons.

I have the follow code:

```
import os
import json
import facebook
import requests

if  __name__ == '__main__' :
    token = os.environ.get('FACEBOOK_TEMP_TOKEN')

    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(token)
    posts = graph.get_connections('me', 'posts')

    while True :
        try:
            with open ('my_posts.jsonl', 'a') as f:
                for post in posts['data']:
                    f.write(json.dumps(post)+"\n")
                posts = requests.get(posts['paging']['next']).json()
        except KeyError:
            break
```

My console don't return any error but the json file generated is a empty one. When i debug it in Idle, that said: KeyError: 'paging'.

Answer (score 0):

When the result doesn't contain a next page, there won't be a paging key returned. Assuming that your code is working like it should, you could ad an extra check to see if the paging key is available or not, like:

```
if 'paging' in posts:
    posts = requests.get(posts['paging']['next']).json()
```

Comment: I try add this line, but nothing changes except the script runs forever. I thought is so much information to download, so i try the limit to 1, but nothing happens... the file either increase your size in the finder